# How'd they do it: TF2 payload cart glow?

Tags: graphics, shaders, unity, glow

How did the creators of TF2 make the glow on the payload cart visible through walls? Is it possible to implement this in Unity's shaderlab?

Comment: This should get you started http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/16391/how-can-i-reduce-aliasing-in-my-outline-glow-effect

Comment: check out [this shader](http://www.unifycommunity.com/wiki/index.php?title=Silhouette-Outlined_Diffuse) from the unify wiki. this is very close to the shader your looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a shader that only draws when occluded by other geometry, use [ZTest Greater](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Components/SL-CullAndDepth.html). To always draw, use ZTest Always. Ensure your shader is late in the [render queue](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Components/SL-SubshaderTags.html). The glow itself is a different problem, personally I like rim lighting effects for such things - like inner glow rather than outer glow.